# Wordpress: Get Parent Menu Nav Item

Tags: wordpress

I need a code to get the Parent Menu Nav Item (Not Parent Page Nav Item) from a special Menu Item in Wordpress.

```
Example: get_parent_menu_nav_item($item->ID)
```

I spent a lot of time in google by this problem, but no solution.

My existing Code for my Menu (for example):

```
<?php
class MV_Cleaner_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker {
    var $tree_type = array( 'post_type', 'taxonomy', 'custom' );
    var $db_fields = array( 'parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id' );
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
    }
    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
    }
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
        $class_names = $value = '';
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes = in_array( 'current-menu-item', $classes ) ? array( 'current-menu-item' ) : array();
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = strlen( trim( $class_names ) ) > 0 ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';
        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', '', $item, $args );
        $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';
        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $value . $class_names .' id="NEED PARENT ID">';
        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
    function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth) {
        $output .= "</li>\n";
    }
}
?>
```

I hope you can help me, thanks a lot for answers.

Comment: I suppose the obvious $item->menu_item_parent is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, but I search something similar... Yan you help me?

Comment: If $item->menu_item_parent isn't what you are looking for I have no idea what you mean by parent menu nav item. $item->menu_item_parent corresponds to the menu item that has $item as a child menu item.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to append a class to the parent `<li>` inside of `start_el`. Not going well.

Answer (score 6):

This is an old thread, but today I have a requeriment to show parent menu title and I solved it using some code from core, just load the metadata using $item->menu_item_parent and then use the right function to get the parent object

```
$object_id = get_post_meta( $item->menu_item_parent, '_menu_item_object_id', true );
$object    = get_post_meta( $item->menu_item_parent, '_menu_item_object',    true );
$type      = get_post_meta( $item->menu_item_parent, '_menu_item_type',      true );

if ( 'post_type' == $type ) {
    $title = get_post( $object_id )->post_title;
} elseif ( 'taxonomy' == $type) {
    $title = get_term( $object_id, $object )->name;
}
```